# Finder - undo close window for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, finder, undo

I would like to know if there is any utility for Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) that can "undo" closing of Finder windows - much like tabs in a web browser have the "undo close tab" feature:

[image]

My initial Google searching just brings up lots of keyboard shortcut lists, and I can't find any questions covering this topic on Super User.

I like the `Finder.app` just fine aside from this 'flaw', so I'm not really interested in using a Finder replacement (except if it is `XtraFinder` as shlck pointed out - that looks pretty nice and seems to integrate with the existing finder). Still interested to know if there is another option, tho.

Comment: XtraFinder should have this feature IIRC

Comment: that looks so good i'm going to edit the question to remove the "no finder replacement" stipulation so you can put that as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finder on its own can't do this.

The [XtraFinder add-on](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) gives Finder a new tab feature with the same functionality as in web browsers. Open a tab with ⌘T, and undo closing a tab with ⇧⌘T, or by right-clicking the *New Tab* button.

XtraFinder is not a complete Finder replacement, so you just get the additional features without losing the actual Finder.